# Angular and ASP.NET Core Role-Base Problem

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, roles

I'm working on an Angular web application with ASP.NET Core backend. I have a problem with the Roles. After a successful login I receive a token, which contains the user's role, but I always get this answer from the asp.net when I try to call a method: http://localhost:5000/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2FClient%2Fdetails. Why? The token is valid and it didn't expire.

Angular:

```
getAllWithContactDetails(): Observable<ClientContact[]> {
  console.log(`here: ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`);
  return this.http.get<ClientContact[]>(`${links.API_URI}/api/Client/details`, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
    })
  });
}
```

ASP.NET Core

```
//Controller:
[HttpGet("details"), Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Employee,Seller")]
public IEnumerable<ClientContact> GetClientsWithContactDetails()
{
    ...
}

//Login:
...

var tokeOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
    issuer: jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)],
    audience: jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)],
    claims: new List<Claim>() {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result.First())
    },
    expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10),
    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
);

return Ok(new { Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokeOptions) });
```

`ConfigureServices` of the `Startup.cs`:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
        });

        services.AddDbContext<WebApiContext>(opt =>
           opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SlkDatabase")));

        var jwtAppSettingOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)],

                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)],

                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,

                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };
        });

        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WebApiContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebApi", Version = "v1" });
        });

        services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
    }
```

Response:

[image]

Comment: You mean by "but I always get this answer from the asp.net when I try to call a method:"
that the server responds with a redirect to `http://localhost:5000/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2FClient%2Fdetails` for each request that you make even if you are already authenticated?

Comment: Exactly. I don't know why does it want to redirect me to the /Account/Login page (which doesn't exist). The route to the Login page is simply /login.

Comment: Could you please share the `ConfigureServices` of the `Startup.cs`?
I suspect that `AddDefaultIdentity` configuration might be used, which wants to use the default Razor pages and redirects of Identity. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityservicecollectionuiextensions.adddefaultidentity?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Is this a proper redirect response with HTTP code 301/302? Or just some weird bug that results in this string response with status code 200?

Comment: Oh, yes, good idea from Milan; I remember encountering the same issue. I won't write an answer, because it was his idea. :)

Comment: 1. I've added `ConfigureServices`. 2. Redirect response is with HTTP code 404

Comment: @Leaky thank you for waiting for me to check the idea with `AddDefaultIdentity`. :) Based on the updated post it seems not to be the case. The request-response pipeline might be not able to handle the token, that is created in the `GetClientsWithContactDetails` action method. But I don't see, exactly why, so if you have an idea you can post it as an answer. :)

Comment: It seems to me that there is still some issue with respect to redirect, since 404 appears to relate to an login endpoint, even though the original request is sent to a different endpoint. I think one problem will be that I can't see role support added with `AddRoles<IdentityRole>()` before calling `AddEntityFrameworkStores()`, and from what I remember that's needed when `AddIdentity()` is used. Also, I experienced some weird conversion issue with `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`, so I suspect that `JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub` should be used instead. But I don't have anything concrete. :/

Answer (score 1):

So, I managed to reproduce the problem in a new project, using your configuration. And while doing so I remembered that I ran into the exact same issue previously.

The problem is that you're calling `AddAuthentication()` first, and then `AddIdentity()`.

#### Solution

In `ConfigureServices()`, you have to call `AddIdentity()` first, and then `AddAuthentication()` with your custom authentication options.

#### Cause

What is happening in the background is that the `AddIdentity()` extension method is calling a bunch of other extension methods to add the services Identity deems necessary, with the configuration it deems necessary. Part of this is calling `AddAuthentication()` with its own authentication options.

So, it simply overwrites your authentication options if you call it after calling `AddAuthentication()`. This causes that horrible redirection behavior (it does a proper 302 redirect btw, I checked it).

---

Let me know if this solves this issue. Also let me know if you are experiencing additional issues with your role-based authorization, because I suspect that you will. *(Edit: I tested role authorization too, and actually it worked for me.)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already solved the problem by changing `AddIdentity` to `AddDefaultIdentity`.

Comment: Oki, but you should still place your `AddAuthentication` after `Add(Defaullt)Identity(Core)` if you want to use your own authentication over Identity's, no matter which of the confusing Identity extension methods do you use. :) `AddDefaultIdentity` also contains a call to `AddAuthentication` with its own authentication settings (plus cookies, plus UI), it just happens not to cause the issue you experienced. But I suppose nothing guarantees that they won't change this extension method in ways that will cause issues in the future.